# Why do my webfonts no longer work on the iOS mail client?

Tags: ios, css, email, html-email, webfonts

A few months ago, my webfonts stopped worked on the iOS mail client. [I'm not the only one to have experienced this.](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/7794-google-fonts-not-working-in-ios-mail)

The code I am using is this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" id="magazine-font-aleo-css" href="https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo.css" type="text/css">`

You can [view the resulting CSS](https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo.css) for yourself, but here's an extract:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aleo';
    src: url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.svg#aleoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font is then applied inline on the body tag.

`<body style="background-color:#f0f0f0; color:#333; font-family:Aleo, serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:400; line-height:1.625;margin:0;">`

I can't find any documentation as to what's changed on iOS. I'd be glad to receive answers that either (a) tell me what the problem is, or (b) give advice on how I can diagnose the issue.

Comment: You don't seem to have a url to link to the font to your email. The CSS doesn't have one either.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you could try:

---

**1.** The Litmus thread you linked suggests using `@import` instead of `<link>` to reference the font files. So:

```
<style>
  @import url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo.css);
</style>
```

---

**2.** I've had recent success getting web fonts to display in iOS Mail using the `<link>` tag, but my code looks like this:

```
<!--[if mso]>
  <style>
    * {
      font-family: sans-serif !important;
    }
  </style>
<!--<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:700" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This hides the `<link>` tag from Outlook, which seems to choke on it and cause problems. I've just tested this in Litmus and it display the web font.

---

Another thing to check with your original code is to move as and hard-code full URLs.

```
<style>
  @import url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo.css);
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Aleo';
    src: url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('https://www.evangelicalmagazine.com/wp-content/themes/evangelical-magazine/fonts/aleo/Aleo-Regular-webfont.svg#aleoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```